# Re: Julius Speech Recognition

Tags: julius-speech

I am using julius speech recognition for my application. I have one doubt regarding julius:

I have downloaded the latest version and was successful in using its lib and making it work. the problem I am facing is..once the app starts and I call the voice recognition function in my application...it takes the input from mic and displays whatever is said in the mic, but the function still continues to do so again and again. The control will never come out of that function. Here I am facing problem since the control is not returning back I am not able to proceed further. What I want is once the engine gets input from mic it should recognize and stop there.. which I tried to do by deleting the callback function but was unsuccessful.

Can anyone please guide me in this matter, what I need to do to get the desired output. It will be helpful for me.

Comment: Hi, Welcome to Stackoverflow. You might want to refer http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 0):

As discussed in [the same post on VoxForge](http://voxforge.org/home/forums/message-boards/speech-recognition-engines/re-julius-speech-recognition):

> You have a couple of choices: first to use the Julius -input control to get the sound data from a list of files (see the .jconf sample file), so that when the list (even if only length one) is exhausted then Julius stops. It is quite easy to record the voice input to a file and then feed the file into Julius. Second you can put a dialog manager in control. If you need more information on what a dialog manager does there are many posts on this forum on that subject accessible by a search.
>
> The basic function of Julius is to start up and then keep on decoding input. When you get more experience you can run Julius as a server, and then tell the server to respond, not respond or shut down as required. It's more efficient than having Julius start and stop all the time.

When an avenue exists for a complex application to yield the required result by using an effective combination of options at run time, editing the application, while possible, might involve a lot of unnecessary work. The emphasis then shifts to passing the options correctly in whatever script is being used to access Julius.